# How to get a combined column with NULL string as well if exists in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with firstname, middlename, lastname. How do I merge these columns so that I have one column with fullname including NULL for middlenname in between if it is not there in data ex: john?

```
df
  first_name middle_name last_name
0        bob           K     smith
1       john                 smith
2       bill           R     smith
```

output

```
  full_name
0 bobKsmith
1 john smith
2 billRsmith
```

Comment: can you provide the dictionary used to create dataframe?

Comment: import pandas as pd
data = {'first_name': ['bob', 'john', 'bill'], 
        'middle_name': ['K','', 'R'], 
        'last_name': ['smith', 'smith', 'smith']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: @Vedant - any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
df.replace('', " ", inplace = True)
df["concat"] = df.sum(axis = 1)
```